# Proper way to use a transaction around multiple inserts or updates

Tags: sql-server, transactions

What is the proper way to test for insert/update failures and rollback this transaction if there are any? I don't think what I have will work since my inserts/updates are 3 separate statements and the @@ROWCOUNT will only reflect the last statement executed.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION Script;
GO

INSERT INTO TableA (id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO TableB (id) VALUES (1)
UPDATE TableC SET id=1 WHERE id=2
GO

IF (@@ROWCOUNT=3 AND @@ERROR=0)
    BEGIN
    COMMIT
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: Rolling back transaction'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Script
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you put SET XACT_ABORT ON before you start transaction, [in case of an error, rollback will be issued automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx).

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

begin transaction

INSERT INTO TableA (id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO TableB (id) VALUES (1)
UPDATE TableC SET id=1 WHERE id=2

commit transaction
```

If you want to do rollback yourself, [use try .. catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx).

```
begin transaction

begin try

  INSERT INTO TableA (id) VALUES (1)
  INSERT INTO TableB (id) VALUES (1)
  UPDATE TableC SET id=1 WHERE id=2

  commit transaction

end try

begin catch
  raiserror('Message here', 16, 1)
  rollback transaction
end catch
```

Comment: will the SET XACT_ABORT ON attribute raise an error message when the transaction rollbacks ?

Comment: @Raza Yes. Xact_abort will break the execution flow and rollback automatically. Error will still be delivered to client.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what version you're on, but there has been try/catch since SQL 2005:

```
begin transaction
begin try
   INSERT INTO TableA (id) VALUES (1)
   INSERT INTO TableB (id) VALUES (1)
   UPDATE TableC SET id=1 WHERE id=2
end try
begin catch
   SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
   while(@@trancount > 0)
   begin
      rollback transaction
   end
end catch
if (@@trancount <> 0)
begin
   commit transaction;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Failing inserts will throw. "Failing" updates can be detected using @@ROWCOUNT.